# How to open large DBF Files (6GB) in Lazarus/Pascal

Tags: delphi, lazarus, dbf

I am new here and this is my first post. So here goes my question:
I created an application to import data from DBF/CSV/TXT files to a MySql Database. Everything works perfect, except when I select a DBF file larger than 3GB of size. I am using the TDBF component for Lazarus 1.4.0 (FPC 2.6.4). I also tried the Devart UniDac component suite with no luck.
So, does anyone know of a component/library/way, free/paid, which I can use to perform this task directly in my application?

> P.S.: I know for sure that those tables are working and NOT corrupted,
>   because I can open them via a software called DBFView
>   (www.dbfview.com). But I need to import these files through my
>   application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asking for recommendations for a tool, library, software, documentation, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic here, as is explained in the [help].

Comment: Please show us the code as to how you are importing the files.

Comment: Hello Bernd Linde,
There is no problem with the code. I can open tables smaller than 2GB with no problem. What it seems to be is a limitation of the component to open large DBF files. I heard that standard DBF files have a limit of 2GB. But these files I have seem have been created by Flagship or some other XBase variation.

Comment: You didn't answer anymore on the lazarus forum... but did you remove the index files? (the index files could cause problems during the opening of such large files). Also... including some code could help... if you use some properties or functions which traverse the entire file during/around opening it could crash the whole thing. Otherwise you need a very small component or library which does raw reading. No first/last/lookup and other stuff. Just opening the file and reading record by record.

Comment: Did you try to disable all forms of indexing on your tdbf component? If any?

Comment: Hey Guys, 
I have tried to open the 6GB table using all possible (known by me) properties of the TDBF component. Disabled all possible indexes, tried all available Table Level and Open Mode options. Nothing worked.
I believe that the programs I use to open those large files were written in another, more powerful languange such as C/C++, Java. What do you think?

Comment: There is no such thing as "more powerful than Pascal" :) Kidding aside... it could just be that tdbf uses an Integer to determine it's position within the file. And an integer only goes up to 2.147.483.647 (which isn't enough for 6GB). But it's definitely not due to lack of support for large files in FPC/Lazarus. We already pointed out... if you read the header-record (with the fields) yourself you could just raw-read the entire file. You could also try to find out where it goes wrong in tdbf and see if you/we can fix it. But since I don't have a 6GB DBF-file on hand I can't test this myself.

Comment: You didn't even state where it goes wrong. During Opening of the table or during reading.

Comment: @jufau I can confirm tDbf doesn't support DBF-files over 2GB. For more discussion see: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,28994.msg183358.html#msg183358 (discussions on stackoverflow isn't really appropriate/easy.)

Answer (score 0):

The standard ODBC set-up on Windows (Win7 and earlier at least) includes a dBase driver.  So, try:

- Setting up an ODBC DSN for your dBase files
- Accessing it via the FPC/Lazarus equivalent of Delphi's TAdoQuery in your project, if there is one.

The point, of course, of trying this way is that it avoids the need to use a DBF-specific dataset component in your project.

PS Try rephrasing your question so that it asks how to access dBase files *without* using a 3rd-party library.  Might attract fewer "off-topic" objections then.